# JVM- how to find and compare which JVM is better for linux? JAMVM vs OPENJDK.

Tags: memory-management, jvm, java, jamvm

Is there any tool to compare memory footprint of different JVMs. currently running on JAMVM.
I want to know, how to compare JVM. and what are the deciding factors.

Answer (score 1):

The best tool I know of to compare memory footprints is to run your program under each and use `top` or `time` to monitor its memory usage. `/usr/bin/time` (not the one built in to your shell) will output the maximimum memory size used by the program in the course of its run. Bear in mind that this will count varying overhead, and may vary greatly across program types.

As far as generally comparing, you ask "what are the deciding factors". The deciding factors are whatever matters for your program or use case. It sounds like memory is something you care about; measure it. If you care about wall-clock time or CPU time used, measure that. Determine what makes or breaks your application, and measure those things. There aren't necessarily general principles (though it is possible for one to be better in general than others), you'll need to determine what works best for your specific application and use case.